# How does thumbnails settings and changes work in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, e-commerce, thumbnails, spree

I'm building my first Spree application and my own layout/theme for it. I need to change thumbnail sizes for products and have been directed differently, mostly it seems to be an unpopular subject. How does this work and how do I change it?

#### Spree configuration

config/initializers/spree_config.rb

```
Spree::Config.set(
    attachment_styles: "{
        \"mini\":\"48x48>\",
        \"small\":\"110x110>\",
        \"product\":\"340x340>\",
        \"large\":\"650x650>\"
    }"
)
```

That is how I tried it the first time - no effect.

#### Clearing cache

I tried to clear the cache like so:
`rake tmp:clear` which gave no result.

#### Re-upload?

I tried re-uploading some images to force a re-generation of thumbnails and there *was* results but not for all sizes. For instance, there seems to be really hard to create a 340x340 px image for 'product' size.

What I'm after is a way to re-generate all thumbnails according to my own defined sizes.

`ruby 1.9.3p194 | Rails 3.2.8 | Spree 1.2.0`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to the Spree Administrator Dashboard > Configurations > Image Settings. Click edit and change the paperclip styles field and click update.

Run the command.

```
bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails class=Spree::Image
```

You would not need to re-upload the images that are already there, the rake command would re-generate the thumbnails.

Comment: Don't seem to see image settings option on spree 3.1.0.

Comment: In my Spree 3.1. this rake command in heroku  errors:" 
 No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/public/spree/products/48/original/Yellowfish-front.png
exception while processing Spree::Image ID 49:" Do you have any clue what wrong?